# Reusing jQuery Moblile CSS rules

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I've created an app with jQuery Mobile. Now I want to have a desktop browser version of the same app, and I'm unable to figure out how to best do that.

Is there a way I could reuse the data-role="button",  data-role="collapsible", data-theme="b", data-transition="fade" etc that creates the jQuery mobile widgets?

Thanks for any help.

**edit**: 
In jqm the accourdion is created using data-role="collapsible", but in jQuery UI it seems like I must call a .accordian() function. Similar, in the jqm I could easily create a popup using a data-role="dialog", but in jqui I need to do a .dialog(). And yes, I'm a newbiw here, so I might have got it all wrong!

Comment: Hmmmm... yes I'm a css newbie, but is the question so stupid it need to be downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use it as it is.. no need to change those.

Comment: I've updated the question. Could you explain it? How to create the accordian out of the data-role="collapsable"?

Comment: im not getting it. why can't u use jquery mobile in the desktop site too. whats the need of using  jQuery UI ?

Comment: Don't want the mobile look. (rounded corners etc) but could create a new mobile theme instead of using one of the jqurey ui. I see there's something I've not understand. Thanks for looking into this. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: yups, u can create a new theme using the themeroller depending on how u want it to be.